# Skrollr classes being added, but transition is not occurring on svg path

Tags: wordpress, svg, skrollr

I'm trying to set up some svg paths with skrollr on this page of my site: http://erinwilder.me/portfolio/main-street/

I have the latest version of skrollr called in my footer (it came with my theme). I added the skrollr init, but I have also tested without it.

This is the code I am using for my svg:

```
<svg id="imac" width="555px" height="444px"><path id="imac-inner" style="fill:none; stroke:#000000; stroke-width:2; stroke-linecap:round; stroke-dasharray: 4565; stroke-dashoffset: 4565;" data-0="stroke-dashoffset: 4565;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;" d="M183.53,439.19v2.61c0,1,30.71,1.19,58.06,1.19,13.84,0,27.18,0,35.28,0s21.21,0,35,0c27.35,0,57.59-.18,57.59-1.19v-2.61m-184.2.13c2.46,0.24,7.31.42,16.83,0.57s22.43,0.22,39.67.22c8.52,0,16.6,0,23.72,0l11.59,0,11.59,0c7.12,0,15.2,0,23.72,0,17.24,0,30.22-.07,39.68-0.22s14.36-.33,16.83-0.57l0.78-.09c1.77-.23,1.77-0.51,1.77-0.85V437c0-.9-1.31-1.22-10.77-2.67-5.29-.81-11.28-1.73-13.25-2.59-0.4-.18-2.56-2.2-5.32-26.1-1-8.82-1.82-17.92-2.24-24.84H536.15c8.85,0,15.36-7.31,15.36-16.16V17.88C551.51,9,545,2,536.15,2H19.21C10.35,2,2.5,9,2.5,17.88v346.8c0,8.85,7.85,16.16,16.71,16.16H214.32c-0.43,6.92-1.22,16-2.24,24.84-2.76,23.9-4.91,26-5.32,26.13-2,.86-8.06,1.76-13.35,2.57-9.46,1.45-10.87,1.76-10.87,2.65v1.35c0,0.34.1,0.62,1.87,0.85ZM552.5,330.39H3.49M529.75,26.32a1.57,1.57,0,0,0-1.57-1.57H25.83a1.57,1.57,0,0,0-1.57,1.57V308a1.57,1.57,0,0,0,1.57,1.57H528.18a1.57,1.57,0,0,0,1.57-1.57V26.32ZM277.68,15.48a2.09,2.09,0,1,0-2.09-2.09A2.09,2.09,0,0,0,277.68,15.48Zm0,349.44a9.32,9.32,0,1,0-9.33-9.32A9.32,9.32,0,0,0,277.68,364.93Zm62.14,15.9H214.19"></svg>
```

On the page, there should be a computer drawing itself around the outlined image in the section title "The Website."

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The console throws an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: skrollr is not defined` and there's no indication that the script is added to the page, double check how you're adding skrollr.

Comment: @Duopixel Thanks for the quick response, I get no console errors though. I also can see where the script is included and initialized in the footer.

Comment: working now. Where is the code where you actually use skrollr to animate the svg? Append it to your question.

Comment: @Duopixel So you're supposed to just put the "data-0=" and "data-end=" attributes on your path and Skrollr automatically runs it. You can see that code in the snippet I pasted for my svg.